# Shoot object to mouse position direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to force my object to my mouse position, I mean force it in direction between my object and mouse position, I use this code:

```c#
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 direction = (Vector2)(transform.position - Input.mousePosition);
    direction.Normalize();

    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(-direction, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

But it seems its not works correctly...

Comment: What about it doesn't work? What happens when this code executes? Have you confirmed the code executes?

Comment: its executes but it shoot in wrong direction

Comment: then just remove the minus at `-direction` :)

Comment: No @TimothyGroote , its not exactly the minus direction. It gets my mouse position in all over my 2 monitors! But i really want to do this in my game view only. Direction never be (0,0) even if my cursor is on my object.

Comment: have you try converting your object position to screen position ?

Comment: Vector3 screenPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector2 direction = (Vector2)(screenPos  - Input.mousePosition);

Comment: To explain @joreldraw

Comment: Yep @joreldraw, it works, that is my bad. i must get ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
        Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        Vector2 direction = (Vector2)(Input.mousePosition-screenPoint);
        direction.Normalize();

        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(direction, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use iTween also if you want a smother and a more controlled movement:

http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/index.php

Comment: Nop. Its physics base and the ball that shoots, have collision.

Comment: Not solve the problem of force to mouse position

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that iTween had a moveToMouse or something like that. I guess that I was wrong, must have mistaken with something else